# How to Update or change value in cypher neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

Is there any update query in cypher using which we can update the property of any node or relationship ?
For e.g. I have following node and relationship:
**NodeA**-[r:relatedTo]-**NodeB**
where **relatedTo** is a relationship having properties like **active** or **inactive**

How can I change this property using cypher query  ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

using `SET` keyword in cypher query, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/query-set.html . (Since I have not came across any update query in cypher like in other RDBMS)

**NodeA**-[r:relatedTo]-**NodeB**
try to set value by : `SET r.<your property name>="<desired value>";` before returning any value from `start n=node(...)... return n;` query.